# Connect Activity Indicator to prototype cells?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, tableview

Hey Guys i wanted to connect a activity indicator to my prototype cell but then i got an error-message that says "Connection activityIndicator cannot have a prototype object as destination".
Is it somehow possible to add a activity indicator to a prototype cell ?

Comment: I had an outlet inside the tableviewController connected to my activity indicator. After disconnect the outlet no error message occurs.

Comment: You should be connecting that outlet to a `UITableViewCell` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an outlet inside the tableviewController connected to my activity indicator. After disconnect the outlet no error message occurs.