# how to create image in cell table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I want create one page in way table view. its display 4 cell that different image and name for any cell. (this information get url in loop)

first : I create one class that I can meaning 2 variable.

Recipe.h
     #import

```
 @interface Recipe : NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; // name of recipe
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageFile; // image filename of recipe


 @end so now in RecipeViewController (root) I write this code :
     #import "RecipeViewController.h"
     #import "Recipe.h"

     @interface RecipeViewController ()
     {
     IBOutlet UIImageView *ab;
     }

     @end

     @implementation RecipeViewController
     {
         NSMutableArray *recipes;
         NSInteger num;
     }
     @synthsize ab;

     - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
     {
         self = [super initWithStyle:style];
         if (self) {
             // Custom initialization
         }
         return self;
     }


     - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
         [super viewDidLoad];

         self.navigationItem.title = @"Recipe Book";
         UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil
 action:nil];
         [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];




         NSString *numberbook = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
 URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.102/mamal/book.php?all"]];

         NSInteger numbook = [numberbook integerValue];


         NSMutableArray *b = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:numbook];

         for (int i = 1; i <= numbook; i++)
         {
             Recipe *si = [Recipe new];
             NSLog(@"%d,%@",i,si);

             NSString *c = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString
 stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.102/mamal/book.php?info=1&b=%d",i]]];

             NSString *a = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.102/mamal/book.php?p=1&b=%d",i];

             [b addObject:a];

             UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:a]]];

             [ab setImage:myImage];

             NSLog(@"%@",a);


             NSLog(@"%@",c);

             si.name = [NSString stringWithString:c];
             si.imageFile =[];   //I so confused!!!


             if(!recipes){
                 recipes = [NSMutableArray array];
             }
             [recipes addObject:si];
         }


         num = numbook;



         // Remove table cell separator
         [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

         // Assign our own backgroud for the view
         self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"common_bg"]];
         self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

         // Add padding to the top of the table view
         UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 0, 0);
         self.tableView.contentInset = inset;

     }

     - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
     {
         [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }

     #pragma mark - Table view data source

     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {
         // Return the number of sections.
         return 1;
     }

     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
         // Return the number of rows in the section.
         return recipes.count;
     }

     - (UIImage *)cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         NSInteger rowCount = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
         NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
         UIImage *background = nil;

         if (rowIndex == 0) {
             background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_top.png"];
         } else if (rowIndex == rowCount - 1) {
             background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bottom.png"];
         } else {
             background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_middle.png"];
         }

         return background;
     }

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         // Configure the cell...
         if (cell == nil) {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         }

         // Display recipe in the table cell
         Recipe *recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
         recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.imageFile];

         UILabel *recipeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
         recipeNameLabel.text = recipe.name;

         UILabel *recipeDetailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
         recipeDetailLabel.text = recipe.detail;

         // Assign our own background image for the cell
         UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

         UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
         cellBackgroundView.image = background;
         cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;


         return cell;
     }

     #pragma mark - Table view delegate

     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
     }

     @end
```

I so confused and get this error :

**"connection cannot have a prototype object as its destination"**

also I don't know one way for display image in cell!!!

Comment: UIImage *background = nil; replace with UIImage *background = [[UIImage alloc] init];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150715/strange-error-when-adding-items-to-prototype-cells-in-storyboard-ib and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381002/connect-activity-indicator-to-prototype-cells

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.imageView.image = yourImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cell.yourImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
```